Long table width expand to upto marginpar width for the stub column layout when table splitting multi pages
I am using stub column layout (major and minor columns) for my work.
I am facing problem for placing long table if the table width is exceeded the text width, i need to move left side or Right side according to the page margin (odd and even side pages ie., table to be  placed up to the margin par width ). currently it is moved outside the page
How to move the left and right margin (based on the odd/even pages) for long table when table splitting multiple pages
MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{array,longtable,showframe}

\setlength{\paperheight}{246truemm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{189truemm}

\setlength\textheight{44\baselineskip}
\setlength\textwidth{308.2pt}            

\setlength\oddsidemargin{39.62pt}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}    
\setlength\evensidemargin{188pt}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}

\setlength\marginparpush{12pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{144pt}

\setlength\topmargin{54.2pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-1in}
\setlength\headheight{10pt} 
\setlength\topskip{9.5pt} 
\setlength\headsep{8.59pt}
\setlength\footskip{75.09pt}
\setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}


\LTcapwidth\textwidth

\begin{document}

\chapter{Long tables expand upto marignpar width}

\begin{longtable}{lllll}
\caption{Explicit directions for branched and unbranched helices with low twist with even numbers of strands in each helix are tabulated in Tables Explicit directions for branched and unbranched helices with low twist with even numbers of strands in each helix are tabulated in Tables} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4th column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5th column}} \\
\hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4th column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5th column}} \\ 
\hline 
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


It's all open source so in theory anything is possible, but basically this is not supported (and might be hard to add) It would be easier if you could ensure that the pages that have the table only have the table. If the longtable starts or ends mid-page things are a lot harder as you only want to shif part of the material passed to the output routine

It seems longtable and flowfram are not compatible (sigh).

@DavidCarlisle do you know why changepage works when the last page is odd, but fails if it is even? (I have a guess, but it is probably wrong.)

@cfr I didn't look but just from basic principles, it is easy to make the table correct for one of the page layouts but the other is harder as you have to shift it. So it's not exactly surprising that one parity is harder to get right than the other, but I didn't look exactly what happens

@DavidCarlisle hmm. I'm not convinced it really works at all.

This uses \getLTwidth and \newgeometry to change the margins.  It uses saveboxes to format the text before and after the longtable.  Note that showframe shows the new margins, not the old margins.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,twoside]{geometry}
\geometry{%
paperheight=246truemm,
paperwidth=189truemm,
textheight=44\baselineskip,
textwidth=308.2pt,
marginparwidth=144pt,% no marginparsep given
left=39.62pt,
top=54.2pt,
headheight=10pt,
headsep=8.59pt,
footskip=75.09pt}

\setlength\marginparpush{12pt}
\setlength\topskip{9.5pt} 
\setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}

\newlength{\LTwidth}% width of next longtable
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getLTwidth}[1][\empty]% #1 = longtable index (optional)
{\bgroup% for \count1 and \LT@entry
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \count1=\value{LT@tables}% default
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \else
    \count1=#1\relax
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{LT@\@roman\count1}{\LTwidth=\textwidth}{%
    \LTwidth=0pt%
    \def\LT@entry##1##2{\advance\LTwidth by ##2}%
    \csname LT@\@roman\count1\endcsname
  }%
  \global\LTwidth=\LTwidth
\egroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array,longtable,lipsum}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}

\begin{document}
\setbox\tempboxa=\vbox{\chapter[Long Table]{Long tables expand upto marignpar width}}% use old geometry
\setbox\tempboxb=\vbox{\lipsum[1-6]}

\getLTwidth
\newgeometry{textwidth=\LTwidth, marginparwidth={\dimexpr \LTwidth-\textwidth-\marginparsep},left=39.62pt}
\unvbox\tempboxa

\begin{longtable}{lllll}
\caption{Explicit directions for branched and unbranched helices with low twist with even numbers of strands in each helix are tabulated in Tables Explicit directions for branched and unbranched helices with low twist with even numbers of strands in each helix are tabulated in Tables} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4th column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5th column}} \\
\hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4th column}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5th column}} \\ 
\hline 
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\\hline
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778& abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}

\setbox\tempboxa=\vsplit\tempboxb to\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
\hspace*{\fill}\parbox[b][\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal][b]{\wd\tempboxb}% even page only
  {\unvbox\tempboxa}

\restoregeometry

\unvbox\tempboxb

\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}

